# Attach a bone to the middle of a B-Bone

Tags: rigging, bones, constraints

I'm wondering if it there any way to attach another bone to the middle of a B-bone.
I tried using Copy Transforms, Child Of constraints, etc, and they all consider the B-bone as being straight even when It's curved, which is the main purpose of using B-bones...
I even tried using a curve to try to emulate the b-bone curve and then I could use Hooks to the control points of the curve, but it's impossible to make the curve have the exact same shape of the B-Bone at all times... unfortunately.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Subdivide the b-bone into two so you have a point in the middle to attach to.

Comment: @sambler Yeah but this way I lose the shape of the single B-Bone, for example If I want one single big curved bone, its impossible to get the exact same curvature with two smaller b-bones.